# SQL Employee attendance record based on swipe-in and swipe-out time on particular date

Tags: mysql

I have a SQL table with the following employee's swipe-in and swipe-out data on a particular date.[Image Link below]

[image: image1]

I need to write an SQL query which produces the following results.[Image Link below]

[image: image2]

Here in the result table working hours means the total time spent by the employee on that particular date.
This is the query what I have tried. I am getting the working_hours but not for a particular date.

```
SELECT emp_card_id 
     , CONCAT(CAST(
       CASE WHEN SUM(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(out_time)
                    -UNIX_TIMESTAMP(in_time)) > 86400
            THEN FLOOR(
                 SUM(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(out_time)
                    -UNIX_TIMESTAMP(in_time)) / 86400 )
            ELSE 0 END AS CHAR)
         , ' days' ) AS working_days
        , SEC_TO_TIME(MOD(
                 SUM(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(out_time)
                    -UNIX_TIMESTAMP(in_time)) , 86400 )
             )  AS working_hours
  FROM EmpAttendance.emp_attendance
GROUP
    BY emp_card_id;
```

Comment: No Images please. Also, Please add what you tried and what's not working

Comment: I have already added the image link.Please click on those links. Please see the updated question.

Comment: @SagarSuri we prefer to not have images of data in these questions since it makes it very hard to replicate your tables on our own systems so we can dig into your problem. You can use an online tool like ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/ to generate nicely formatted text tables here on SO. Just indent them with 4 spaces (or a tab) on each line and they will show up as a fixed width font like code.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. will surely make a note of it before asking any questions next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are on the right track. Just add your date into the SELECT portion of the query as well as the GROUP BY so that you group by both employee AND date:

```
SELECT emp_card_id, `date`
     , CONCAT(CAST(
       CASE WHEN SUM(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(out_time)
                    -UNIX_TIMESTAMP(in_time)) > 86400
            THEN FLOOR(
                 SUM(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(out_time)
                    -UNIX_TIMESTAMP(in_time)) / 86400 )
            ELSE 0 END AS CHAR)
         , ' days' ) AS working_days
        , SEC_TO_TIME(MOD(
                 SUM(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(out_time)
                    -UNIX_TIMESTAMP(in_time)) , 86400 )
             )  AS working_hours
  FROM EmpAttendance.emp_attendance
GROUP
    BY emp_card_id, `date`;
```

Comment: thank you so much! it worked like magic. I got the solution. But if any other efficient solutions you have. Do share as well. Love to learn something new.